# Installing Sybase ASE on Linux

Tags: linux, installation, sap-ase

ALL,

I'm trying to install Sybase ASE Developer Edition  on my Gentoo Linux box.

I downloaded latest release of the ASE (16.02), un-packed it and tried to run the GUI installer. Result below:

```
IgorReinCloud ASE_Suite # ./setup.bin  Preparing to install...
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive... Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

No protocol specified

Graphical installers are not supported by the VM. The console mode
will be used instead...

===============================================================================
SAP Adaptive Server Enterprise                   (created with
InstallAnywhere)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Preparing CONSOLE Mode Installation...

===============================================================================
Introduction
------------

InstallAnywhere will guide you through the installation of SAP
Adaptive Server  Enterprise 16.0 SP02 PL02.

It is strongly recommended that you quit all programs before
continuing with  this installation.

Respond to each prompt to proceed to the next step in the
installation.  If you want to change something on a previous step,
type 'back'.

You may cancel this installation at any time by typing 'quit'.

PRESS <ENTER> TO CONTINUE: quit
```

Since I'm running X + GNOME 3 I was surprised. So I tried to check the install log file. Below is the excerpt from it:

```
====================STDERR ENTRIES==================

GUI mode is not supported : Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable; you may consider checking your DISPLAY environment variable.
__________________________________________________________________________
```

So, next I checked the DISPLAY variable:

```
IgorReinCloud log # set | grep -i display
DISPLAY=:0
```

What am I missing? What value should DISPLAY variable contain in order for install to be successful? I have a laptop with only one display/monitor (no second one attached).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure your DISPLAY environment variable by doing:
export DISPLAY=ip_address:0.0 with ip_address = your IP address you can find with "ifconfig -a"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run the installer with GUI, you can follow these steps in Linux Bash shell:
1. unset DISPLAY
2. Run the ASE installer
Forget to set this DISPLAY variable during the installation.

If you do want to run the installation under GUI mode, you can use third party software, such as exceed/tightVNC. For example, in tightVNC, you can set DISPLAY environment variable in this way:
export DISPLAY=localhost:1.0   <-- 1 - represents the port before you connect Linux by tightVNC.

BTW, you should generate a session before you login Linux box by tightVNC, in this way:
Execute "vncserver" in Linux shell, it will let you know a port number to login Linux in tightVNC.
Then you can login Linux box by using tightVNC like:
:[Port number]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use formatting because your answer is hard to read.